# Get top X percentage based on cumulative sum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

My table looks like this:

```
ID | ItemID | ItemQualityID | Amount | UnitPrice
```

My goal is to find the top x% rows for each `ItemID` + `ItemQualityID` pair based on `Amount` cumulative sum and ordered by `UnitPrice`.

For example:

```
ID | ItemID | ItemQualityID | Amount | UnitPrice 
1      1            1          18         2
2      1            1          1          1
3      1            1          1          1
4      2            1          18         2
5      2            1          1          1
6      2            1          1          1
7      1            1          1          3
```

and I want the top 10%, then the resulting table should contain row #2, 3, 5, 6. Since the total amount for ItemID 1 and 2 are 21 and 20 respectively, thus 10% would be 2 items each. If I want the top 20%, the resulting table should still be the same since if I include row 1 and 4 it would make it 100%. Row #7 has unit price > row #1 so if row #1 is not included then row #7 shouldn't be included as well.

Ideally I want the table with all the filtered rows for some other calculations but I will be happy even if I can only get the sum of Amount * UnitPrice of the filtered table. Something like

```
ItemID | ItemQualityID | Sum
  1            1          2
  2            1          2
```

for the above example.

Comment: I don't see a SQL query in this question

Comment: @JoePhilllips Do you mean you don't think it can be done with SQL query or you want me to post some queries I have tried so far/?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: `Since the total amount for ItemID 1 and 2 are both 20`, shouldn't ItemID 1's total amount be 21?

Comment: @FelixPamittan ops...thx and fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM OVER` :

```
DECLARE @percent DECIMAL(5, 2) = .1

;WITH CteSum AS(
    SELECT *,
        TotalSum    = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID, ItemQualityID),
        CumSum      = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID, ItemQualityID ORDER BY UnitPrice, ID)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    ItemID,
    ItemQualityID,
    [Sum] = SUM(Amount * UnitPrice)
FROM CteSum
WHERE CumSum <= @percent * TotalSum
GROUP BY ItemID, ItemQualityID
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/461131)</kbd>

Comment: this looks great! I have a quick question : why would the Sum become CumSum after you added the ORDER BY clause inside Over clause?

Comment: The addition of `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause [specifies logical order in which the window function calculation is performed.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @FelixPamittan Just curious :) Is marking `Online Demo` inspired by `LiveDemo` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305570/in-sql-what-does-concatcol1-col2x-does/36305608#36305608)?

Comment: @lad2025, yup. Definitely got it from you.