# In SQL what does concat(col1,col2)x does?

Tags: sql

I'm reading a documentation about SQL injections, and there is a strange statement that i don't understand:

```
concat(col1,col2)x
```

What is the use of the `x` ?

Comment: `concat` - returns a string that is the result of concatenating two or more string values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is the use of the x ?*

It is column [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29):

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col1 VARCHAR(100), col2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO tab(col1, col2) VALUES ('a','b');
```

Query:

```
SELECT concat(col1,col2)x
FROM tab
```

same as

```
SELECT concat(col1,col2) AS x
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/QINZN9645)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╗
║ x  ║
╠════╣
║ ab ║
╚════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` - returns a string that is the result of concatenating two or more string values.

The confusion is about the x. The x is the concated single name, so you can access it. You can also place `AS` before the x.

**Query:**

```
SELECT CONCAT ( 'Happy ', 'Birthday ', 11, '/', '25' ) AS Result;
```

**Output:**

> Happy Birthday 11/25

Answer (score 0):

**X is an Alias**

For Sql server 2012

```
Select concat('Abc',null,'def') as X
```

o/p

```
 X
------
Abcdef
```

in traditional Way

```
select 'abc'+null+'xyz' as X
```

o/p

```
 X
------
null
```

so basically **concate** function avoid null value during Concatenation of string while tradition approach  will not allow to concate string with null .

Comment: The question is not about the `concat()` call it's about the `x` after it